# How does AWS EC2 scale if more resourses needed?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I launched a **t1.micro** instance running Apache and MySQL servers on Ubuntu. Basically I'm using it to host my photo sharing app that may have huge random spikes in terms of visitors.

How does AWS go about it?

Will the instance automatically upgrade to appropriate horse power to keep up with demand and growing storage demands?

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to manually make your instance more powerful by first making sure it is in the stopped state (this requires EBS volumes or you'll lose your data), then going to the AWS console, right click your instance and select 'Change Instance Type'.

If you are interested in a more automated approach, I suggest an Elastic Load Balancer with an Auto-scaling policy. With Auto-scaling, Amazon will spin up or down new instances based on set points that you provide (i.e. CPU usage reaches 80% for 10 minutes).

Comment: where do i find the 'Auto-scaling policy'?

Comment: Amazon's documentation can help you create one. http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/